# Html Input Text Value from Asp:button

Tags: javascript, c#

how can I take a value from an Html field and pass it to an asp: button CommandArgument by javascript

For example:

```
<div runat="server" class="divMain">

<input type="text" id="txtFilterDate" class="datepicker" 
onchange="refillGridBoletas()" />

<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" 
CommandArgument="**txtFilterDate.value**"  Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>


<div>
```

Comment: Looks like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

CommandArgument property is in ViewState. it is a server side property and it is impossible to change with js

Comment: even though the elements are inside a form runat = server?

Comment: <div runat="server" class="divMain">
<div id="lblFilterDate" class="font">Filtro por data de liquidação</div>
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" CommandArgument="javascript:window.parent.document.getElementById('txtFilterDate').value"  Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<div>

Comment: you can't set CommandArgument like this code. it can be set or get in backend

Comment: why you want use this solution?! i think it's better to change the solution. you can send the textBox value directly to the server